# Output port is becoming "uninitialized" in GLS (VHDL '93)

Tags: vhdl

I have a block inside a top_block, and it's output is connected to the output port of the top_block. Both have a data type of std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0).
In RTL simulation, the output port of the top_block is getting the correct values. But in GLS, that output port is becoming "uninitialized"... So I tried to do some experiment and changed the data type to std_logic_vector and the issue has been solved.

Now, I don't know what happened. I'm not sure if this is the correct solution to the problem since I can't explain why it is working. So, kindly help me to analyze what happened here and if this is the correct solution to the problem. What is happening during GLS that causes this issue?

Take note that it is just simply connecting the output port of the sub-block to the output port of the top block. The output port of the sub-block is working fine but the wire connecting it to the output port of the top block is "unitialized".

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. We added the -noacg option of irun and the GLS is now passing. The "uninitialized" issue has gone.